# Why does calling a QFileDialog::getSaveFileName() reset installed Qt message handler on linux?

Tags: c++, linux, qt

Сalling a dialog resets a message handler in debian like linux

And yes, no details are required here anymore, but I have to add this text to go through the smart bot

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QDebug>

QtMessageHandler defaultHandler;

void messageHandler(QtMsgType type, const QMessageLogContext &context, const QString &msg)
{
    auto str = msg;
    str.append(" handled");
    defaultHandler(type, context, str);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    qDebug() << "test0";
    defaultHandler = qInstallMessageHandler(messageHandler);
    qDebug() << "test1";
    QFileDialog::getSaveFileName();
    qDebug() << "test2";
}
```

output in windows

```
test0
test1 handled
test2 handled
```

output in debian like linux

```
test0
test1 handled
warning: QFSFileEngine::open: No file name specified
debug: test2
```

Comment: I've tested your program in openSUSE right now, using Qt 5.6, 5.9, 5.12 and 5.14 and I got the same output as you get in windows. I don't see the warning either. Your problem may be related to the native file dialog in your linux desktoop. What happens if you use `QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog`?

Comment: If your code has several `QFileDialog` calls, then you may want to use `QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_DontUseNativeDialogs)` to set the option globally (Qt >= 5.7).

Comment: Thanks dude, you're cool!

Comment: @Pedro, you should probably convert your comments into an answer.